# Display "Date" data type from SQL table on page using substrings PHP

Tags: php, sql, date

I've got a date stored in my database in the following format "0000-00-00" which is YYYY-MM-DD

I'm wanting to take it take this and convert it to a string that says the date, month in words and the year. As in convert 1993-03-18 to 18 March 1993.

This is what I have so far on my test server (so please no funny comments about getting injected)

```
$dob_form = mysql_query("select dob from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"); 
$dob_day = substr($dob_form, -2);
$dob_mth = substr($dob_form, -5, 2);
$dob_mtc = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $dob_mt) );
$dob_yr = substr($dob_form, -10, 4);
$dob_display = $dob_day + " " + $dob_mtc + " " + $dob_yr;
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong and/or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

use this

```
select date_format(dob,'%d %M %Y') from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I have my inline php `<? echo $dob_form; ?>` it returns "Resource id #4"?

Comment: @dpdesign: mysql_query() returns a statement HANDLE. you need to use mysql_fetch_array() to actually fetch a row from that result.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("select date_format(dob,'%d %M %Y') as dob from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'", $connection); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
echo " $row['dob'];  should be the way

Comment: @Marc B sorry I don't understand? I've got one further up on my page that is used for calling data from the database.

Satya Thanks but that came up blank. :(

Comment: `$dob_form` is a resource handle, representing the results of your query. it is NOT the field you selected in the query. you have to do `$row = mysql_fetch_array($dob_form); echo $row['dob'];` instead. http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: @Marc B Thanks so Much! That works perfectly! Now I'm just working on the kinks for my substrings. :). Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) combined with [`date()`](http://php.net/date) is a typical PHP combo.

```
$dob_form = mysql_query("select dob from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
// get query result...
echo date('d F Y', strtotime($result['dob']));
```

**Note**: Be mindful of any timezone differences between your MySQL and PHP server.

Comment: Thanks but that one didn't really work for what I was looking for. :)

Comment: `r` was just a sample. I was trying to *teach you to fish*. See the update.

Comment: :). Thanks but I'm meaning it didn't pull it out in the way I was looking for.

Comment: You're not completing the *get query result* step.